# Convert Herz datas for x axis and display it with round seconds and minutes

Tags: d3.js

I've got datas in Hz or frames (60Hz or 60frames by seconds) and I need to display them with d3js in a more explicite way with minutes and seconds ("%M'%S") if my domain of time is very large, only seconds ("%S''") if my domain is under 1 minute, and only frames (with f added) if my domain is under 2 seconds.

If I simply do `d3.axisTop(x).tickFormat(function (d) {return d / 60;});` it displays 62 instead of 1'02 and 0.25 instead of 15f (15th frame).

I don't know if I should convert my data first with date ? and use multiformat conditions ?

Comment: This needs more clarity. I don't understand your question well enough.

d = 60 should give 1'  (?)

d = 15 should give 15f (?)

Hz is 1/s, but your output is in minutes and seconds? That's inverted. I don't follow.

Comment: It would be great if you could post a working codepen with some sample data being used inside of it.

Comment: I hope it will work... It's my first codepen : https://codepen.io/kilden/pen/WNXeOJE

Comment: Sorry for the unclear question. Imagine it's datas based on images from a movie : 25i/s. Like this, precision of datas is 25 frame/s. In my codepen, you will see I did two axes (one which is correct, in frames, and a second one that I tried to convert). Of course the second one is false... The first second should be at the 25th frame. How would you correct this ? Would create another object, copy all datas, and then convert frames datas in seconds to generate a good axis ? (note: I got a lot of datas) Or is there another solution ?

Comment: I think I understood an easy way : https://codepen.io/kilden/pen/QWOLQQb

Comment: Think it's a bit clearer now. 50 Hz is 50 frames per second, or 1 frame every 20ms. 1Hz is 1 frame every second and so on. Do you want to show that?

Comment: Yes, but I think it works in my last codeine.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Everything works fine with my last codepen. I just wanted precise seconds and you help me a lot to find the answer with your questions. Sorry for my late answer. (I didn't get a notification that you post again). Thank you anyway.